# checkbox not clicked by webdriver

Tags: webdriver, testng

I have a check box next to the text "I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions" in a registration page. During playback, i can see 
some clicking is happening . But at the end the check box is still unchecked. why is it so.

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="checkbox_container">
            <input name="newuserXYX.agree" value="true" tabindex="106" id="newuserXYX.agree" onclick="ABC.e.reg.checkuserNameAvailability();" type="checkbox">
            <input id="__checkbox_newuserXYX.agree" name="__checkbox_newuserXYX.agree" value="true" type="hidden"> 
            <label id="registration_Agree" for="newuserXYX.agree">I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
</div>
```

i wrote my testNg code as

```
boolean checked=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='newuserXYX.agree']")).isSelected();

        if(checked==false)
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='newuserXYX.agree']")).click();
```

various approaches  i tried are

```
  @FindBy(how=How.ID_OR_NAME,using="newuserXYX.agree")
  @CacheLookup
  private WebElement iagreeCB;
```

and inside @Test

```
iagreeCB.click();
```

for all these i am getting similar result.

why i am unable to click the checkbox ?.

Comment: Are you getting any exception while doing above exception?

Answer (score 1):

Your Code looks ok to me. Have you checked that the onclick-handler does not interfere with your click? Maybe the username availability check fails (BTW the T&C checkbox is a strange place to check username availability...)